# Are the signals differential?

Tags: voltage, pcb, layout, energy, metering

I want to use this [IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/Atmel-46003-SE-M90E32AS-Datasheet.pdf) for a metering purpose.

Are the signals IxP/IxN & VxP/VxN differential signals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datasheet p.8 clearly specifies them as "differential":

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer